# Appropriate Data Analysis when Criterion has Heavy-Tailed Distribution

Tags: regression, bayesian, quantile-regression, power-law, heavy-tailed

I have a data set where my independent variables (i.e., personality assessment scores) are continuous and follow a normal distribution. The criterion, sales performance, is heavy-tailed and follows a power-law distribution. This is not uncommon with sales data and rather than removing outliers or forcing a normal distribution through some kind of transformation, I'd like to keep the data as is. That said, what data analysis would be appropriate to predict sales performance? Linear regression is a common approach in these situations; however, given it's sensitivity to outliers, it doesn't seem to be the best fit. I've seen people recommend Bayes, quantile regression, or even non-linear regression, but curious what makes most sense under these circumstances.

Comment: The pooled distribution of your response variable is not what is assumed to be normal in linear regression. Your concern is if the error term is normal. However, given the marginal distributions, I am having a hard time thinking of how there could be a linear relationship. A scatter plot will help you establish that.